# VS-Code SOQL Builder Text Editing Mode Dissappeared

Tags: vs-code, vscode-dx

There was a button that provides switching between builder mode and text editing mode of SOQL Builder.

It has dissapeared somehow and I couldn't find the possible reason or any solution.

Is there any solution except uninstalling VS Code completely and installing again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a feature that you switch on the file's tab. Right-click the tab, choose Reopen Editor with..., and choose the new mode you'd like to view. This is noted in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/vscode/en/soql/soql-builder#view-your-query-in-both-soql-builder-and-the-text-editor). Note that you may need to wait for the Salesforce Extension Pack to be fully loaded before you can use this feature, which can take a minute on systems with less resources (slower hard drives, not enough RAM, etc). In addition, you must first save the file as a `.soql` before this option will be available.

[image: Right-click tab menu]

[image: Choose your editor]

Comment: After your answer I have checked "Reopen editor with..." option but it wasn't there. The option came after saving the file. So the reason was not saving the query file.

Comment: @pt_5858 Yeah, I overlooked that in this answer; I'll add that in for future readers.